# Issue with Replace function when editing strings

Tags: vb.net, excel, replace, vba

So currently I am trying to update an old excel file's macro codes so that we can use it with a new program. Though I am new to VB I know some C++ and Java from college so I was able to get just about everything working but this section of code. So basically, we are converting excel information to .CVS and when we do the conversion seems to give some of the information three quotation marks on either side instead of the single set like it is listed in the excel document.

To make a simple fix I just added this extra set of code to search each string for quotation marks and remove all but a single set. Instead it seems to just continue replacing sections of the entire string until there is only 1 quotation mark left...do y'all know what the issue might be?

I know this is some poorly written code especially since I havent moved on to fix the infinite loop BUT the main concern right now is just how I am misusing the Replace function.

```
    For X = 1 To 56
    String2 = Sheets(1).Cells(X, 1)
    Z = 1
    Do While Z <> Len(String2)
        If Mid(String2, Z, 1) = Chr(34) Then
            If Mid(String2, Z + 1, 1) = Chr(34) Then
                String2 = Replace(String2, """", "", Z, 1) 
                        ' Replace(String2, Char(34) + Char(34), "", Z, 1)
                Sheets(1).Cells(X, 1) = String2
                Z = 1
            Else
                Z = Z + 1
                End If
        Else
            Z = Z + 1
            End If
    Loop
    Next
```

The File Information being altered:

> "MH 7 to Tipton1",7.942,1,1,0.22
>   4.9,1,18.8
>   "SINGLE CABLE",15,206.8
>   ""--""",0,0   ^^ This is a string that gets eaten by the Replace
>   function after a few loops. It continues till (",0,0") Previous
>   strings were not altered in operation.
>   0,"""--""",0,"""H""","""--""",100,21.1
>   0,"""--""",0,"""VU""","""U""",200,5.1
>   5.1,"""U""",0,"""N""","""--""",0,0
>   0,"""--""",0,"""H""","""--""",100,21.4
>   0,"""--""",0,"""VU""","""U""",200,6.5
>   0,"""--""",0,"""VD""","""U""",100,11.5
>   0,"""--""",0,"""N""","""--""",0,0
>   0,"""--""",0,"""VU""","""U""",100,11.5
>   0,"""--""",0,"""VD""","""U""",100,11.5
>   0,"""--""",23.1,"""N""","""--""",0,0
>   0,"""--""",0,"""VU""","""U""",100,3.6
>   0,"""--""",0,"""VD""","""U""",100,3.6
>   0,"""U""",120.8,"""N""","""--""",0,0
>   0,"""--""",0,"""H""","""--""",12,30.9
>   "Test4.pll"

Comment: If it is excel-vba then it is not VB.NET as explained on those tags.  If it is VB.NET you are probably better off using a Library like CSVHelper.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

I cant quite tell from your question but if all you are trying to do is replace triple quotes and with single quotes then you can remove the entire do loop and just put

```
string2=replace(string2,"""""""","""")
```

inside the for loop to replace contents of the entire string rather than just each character.

So

```
For X = 1 To 56
    String2 = Sheets(1).Cells(X, 1).value

    String2 = Replace(String2, """""""", """")

    Sheets(1).Cells(X, 1).value = String2

Next
```

or even

```
For X = 1 To 56

    Sheets(1).Cells(X, 1).value = Replace(Sheets(1).Cells(X, 1).value, """""""", """")

Next
```

EDIT

You'll also want to use .value for getting the cell value

Comment: Wow, thanks. Yea that method you suggested is much simpler and it seems the .Value was the issue with the replacement function. It is working properly now so thank you!!

Comment: @IanSeanCoulter glad I was able to help. if you could mark the answer as accepted, it'll help other people in the future. if you have any more questions just link me in them.